# Using Multi Threading in Win32 Api

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

i want to learn how i can use multi threading in win32 api.
i have this course project i need to finish and i did try to make an application like drum pads, (i have multiple button when i hit one, it play a sound ) its pretty easy, but i cannot press the second button while the first button ( sound ) is working.
my tutor said i need to use multi threading.
here is my code.

```
switch (wmId)
{

case 'Q':
{
SendMessage(hQ, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, 0);
PlaySound(TEXT("1.wav"), NULL, SND_ALIAS);
SendMessage(hQ, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, 0);
}
break;
```

https://pastebin.com/uWbA5xNK

Comment: Add the flag `SND_ASYNC` to the `PlaySound` call see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: PlaySound(TEXT("1.wav"), NULL, SND_ASYNC);
like this

Comment: Your tutor is wrong, if that is exactly what they suggested. You need to employ asynchronous programming. Multi-threading is just one of many ways to do that, and certainly not the easiest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (untested):

```
PlaySound (TEXT("1.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
```

Documented at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680) (read it!)

Comment: thanks you its works, but how i can make the first sound i click play in the background. 
thank you

Comment: That's what `SND_ASYNC` is supposed to do - i.e. `PlaySound` should return immediately and the sound should play on until the end of the file.  But like I said - code untested.

Comment: what sould i do to make the sound play in the background while the first one is playing is there anyway in the playsound function or should i use something esle

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.  You want to play a second sound at the same time as the first?  Try it!

Comment: i want to be able to play a second sound while the first one is already playing, two sound at one time

Comment: for example the first button(Q)  wav is 5sc,  and the second button wav (W )is 2sc 
and i play the second wav when the first is at 3sc mark they finish at the same time

Comment: thank you for your help.

Comment: @Jawkinz `PlaySound()` can only play one sound at a time. If you want to overlap multiple sounds, you need to mix them together before you play them. Use Microsoft's [DirectSound API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee416960.aspx), or a 3rd party multimedia library, to handle that mixing and playback for you.

Comment: how i can use it i don't know. 
i did look for direct sound api but didnt knew how to use it

Comment: i dont know where to use in my program, you can check my program in the past bin

Comment: It is beyond the scope of SO's question-and-answer format to teach you how to use a complex API like `DirectSound`, sorry, and @Remy has already told you what the limitations of `PlaySound` are.  Talk to your tutor.